# Error - ImportError raised loading rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework

Tags: django, mongodb

I am making an application with django and mongodb .Previously my application run OK with SQL but now i want to connect it with mongo but I am getting this error again and again.I am using python2.7

I have this error:

> 'rest_framework' is not a valid tag library: ImportError raised loading rest_framework.templatetags.rest_framework: No module named app

my setting.py file is -

```
import os
import admin_app
from django.utils import timezone
import django_mongodb_engine.base
from mongoengine import connect
connect('pom')


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'uj8$6(ol=!w)b3-luqzb=#6(j19gkbrnp2asq6=xt%5*s2ylz('

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

SPATIALITE_LIBRARY_PATH = 'mod_spatialite'
# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'djangotoolbox', 
    'admin_app',
    'celery',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    #'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'djangoflash.middleware.FlashMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.CacheMiddleware',
)


ROOT_URLCONF = 'admin_python.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'admin_app.context_processors.init_menu',
                'admin_app.context_processors.server_urls',
                'djangoflash.context_processors.flash',
            ],
        },
    },
]


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static/")
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
HOST_URL='http://127.0.0.1:8001/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media/")
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'admin_python.wsgi.application'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
SERVER_URL = 'http://localhost:8001/'
WEBAPP_URL = 'http://localhost/webapp_angular/'
USERAPI_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/'
HOST_URL_NEW='http://localhost:8001/media/'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases
"""DATABASES = {'default': {
'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
'NAME': 'admin_db',
'USER': 'root',
'PASSWORD': 'root',
'HOST': 'localhost',
}}"""

DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'pom'
   }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Kolkata'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = False



REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # other settings...

    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [],
}
LOGIN_URL = '/auth/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'admin_app.backend.AuthBackend',
    'mongoengine.django.auth.MongoEngineBackend'
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'admin_app.TblAdmin'

EMAIL_HOST = 'email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'AKIAJB6VACOVZANVTC5A'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'Atu9qbV+X5aiwIlQzVAOVjU/AxkxMDV3X0l0FLWweSn9'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'support@doctorinsta.com'

#LOGGING SETTING 
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'verbose': {
            'format' : "[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s [%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s] %(message)s",
            'datefmt' : "%d/%b/%Y %H:%M:%S"
        },
        'simple': {
            'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'
        },
    },
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'applogfile': {
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'class':'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'drinsta.log'),
            'formatter': 'verbose'
            },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
        },
        'drinsta': {
            'handlers': ['applogfile',],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
        },
    }
}

#We can use the following command to see the keys:
#    python -m memcached_stats 127.0.0.1 11211
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
        'TIMEOUT' : 300 #Default
    }
}
CACHE_BACKEND = 'memcached://127.0.0.1:11211/'

SESSION_ENGINE= 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache'

'''
RabbitMQ configurations begins
'''
#OLD FORMAT:
# BROKER_HOST = "127.0.0.1"
# BROKER_PORT = 5672   # default RabbitMQ listening port
# BROKER_USER = "admin"
# BROKER_PASSWORD = "admin"
# BROKER_VHOST = "admin" #Virtual hosts provide a way to segregate applications using the same RabbitMQ instance. Different users can have different access privileges to different vhost and queues and exchanges can be created so they only exists in one vhost. 

#NEW FORMAT:
BROKER_URL = 'amqp://admin:admin@localhost:5672/admin'
'''
RabbitMQ configurations ends
'''
'''
Celery configurations begins
'''
#CELERY_BACKEND = "amqp"  # telling Celery to report the results back to RabbitMQ
#'amqp' means Advanced Message Queuing Protocol
# CELERY_RESULT_DBURI = ""
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Asia/Kolkata"
#CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='djcelery.backends.cache:CacheBackend'    
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'djcelery.backends.database:DatabaseBackend'

CELERY_IMPORTS = ("tasks", )
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True #If set to True, result messages will be persistent. This means the messages will not be lost after a broker restart. The default is for the results to be transient.
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = None
```

Command prompt -

```
ERROR:root:Error while trying to get django settings module.
Error was: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
Validating models...

0 errors found
July 06, 2017 - 11:43:44
Django version 1.6.11, using settings 'admin_python.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.

pip list -

amqp (1.4.9)

anyjson (0.3.3)

Babel (2.3.4)

backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)

beautifulsoup4 (4.5.1)

billiard (3.3.0.23)

bs4 (0.0.1)

celery (3.1.23)

certifi (2016.2.28)

Django (1.6.11)

django-celery (3.1.17)

django-cors-headers (1.1.0)

django-crispy-forms (1.6.0)

django-datatable (0.2.0)

django-datatables-view (1.13.0)

django-dbindexer (1.6.1)

django-flash (1.8)

django-mongodb-engine (0.6.0)

django-picklefield (0.3.2)

djangorestframework (3.3.2)

djangotoolbox (1.8.0)

flower (0.9.1)

futures (3.0.5)

kombu (3.0.35)

mongoengine (0.13.0)

MySQL-python (1.2.5)

numpy (1.11.1)

pandas (0.18.1)

pip (6.0.8)

pycrypto (2.6.1)

pymongo (3.4.0)

python-dateutil (2.5.3)

python-memcached (1.57)

pytz (2016.1)

razorpay (0.2.0)

requests (2.9.1)

setuptools (12.0.5)

six (1.10.0)

tornado (4.2)

validate-email (1.3)

wheel (0.29.0)

xmltodict (0.10.2)
```

Comment: when and where this error occurs,  please be expressive while asking question? @somyasingh

Comment: when i tried to run my application using  command python manage.py runserver after changing my setting.py file for mongodb connection

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your django-admin to 2.0. Then again run and see

Comment: An explanation would be nice

Comment: I got this type of error and I had Django 1.9 version. Then I again upgraded it to 2.0 and then the rest frame work error didn't rise.